# GVIM - undefined variable: paste#paste_cmd?

Tags: vim

When i start GVIM i get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing D:\gvim\gVimPortable\App\vim\vim72\menu.vim:
line  156:
E121: Undefined variable: paste#paste_cmd
E15: Invalid expression: 'vnoremenu <script> &Edit.&Paste<Tab>"+gP^I' .
paste#paste_cmd['v']
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The corresponding script ships with Vim and should be found at `D:\gvim\gVimPortable\App\vim\vim72\autoload\paste.vim`. Check if it's there. Also, something could have messed with your `'runtimepath'` option; it needs to include `D:\gvim\gVimPortable\App\vim\vim72` (but if that were missing from the start, the `menu.vim` that triggers the autoload script would not have loaded).